# Minimal permission for Truncate table in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have created several Data flows in my SSIS package that execute truncate table as part of the ETL process.  I am running the package via a SQL job that is configured to use service account.

I had initially provided an ALTER authorization for that table to the service account however the DBA's have comeback saying that Alter cant be used and minimal permission need to be assigned to the service account for doing truncate.

For eg.

```
use CoreReferenceStaging
GRANT CONNECT,EXECUTE,SELECT,DELETE, INSERT, UPDATE,ALTER ON database::CoreReferenceStaging TO "INT\svc-w-corerefdata-qa";
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON [PartiesIssuerCreditRating] TO  "INT\svc-w-corerefdata-qa";
```

Currently I am having 16 stored data-flows that perform Truncate table individually. 
I had initially thought of creating 16 store procedures containing Execute permissions but I feel its a maintenance issue just to call one truncate table each. Is there a better way of doing it either by assigning roles etc.

Could you let me know whats the best way to deal with this situation ?

Comment: If the db is just a staging db for moving data through, I don't see why permissions on this database should be any issue to your dba. If the permissions are locked down to the staging db what's the issue there?

Comment: The name is staging but eventually that would be even used the main database by one of the web applications.

Answer (score 1):

To provide minimal permissions, encapsulate the `TRUNCATE` statement in a stored procedure. Either specify an `EXECUTE AS` clause for a database user account with the needed `ALTER TABLE` permission or sign the proc with a certificate based on a user with the permissions. See [Erland Sommarskog's article](http://www.sommarskog.se/grantperm.html#certandbulkcopy) for example scripts for the certificate, user, and `TRUNCATE TABLE` proc. The article also includes a detailed discussion of `EXECUTE AS` versus module signing to grant permissions via stored procedures.

Comment: I prefer not to take the store procedure approach as I would need to create 16 store procedures and provide permissions for each or either I would have to make the stored procedure dynamic

Comment: Why can't a single stored procedure truncate all 16 tables without being dynamic?